# Ubuntu 14.04 hangs when WiFi is on and a browser starts

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I have installed recently a WiFi driver rt7601. It's connected to WiFi. But when I starts chromium, or Firefox Ubuntu freezes.
I tried LAN to connect to internet and there is no problem.

Comment: Which network card do you use ? Try uninstalling the driver

Comment: It's a USB WiFi adapter. Some Chinese company tenda. They gave a renamed driver for RTL named as mt7601Usta.ko after build.